# React client tries to access server resource without access to it gets 404

Tags: reactjs, client-server, next.js

I believe my react code is trying to access a server directory after its compiled and sent to the client. This means when it looks for the gameLogic.js and style.css files it cant locate them. I'm wondering how I would go about getting the react component im working on to get a copy of them and send them off to the remote client. I get the following errors.

pages/game.js

```
import * as React from "react";
import Layout from "../components/Layout";
import Separator from "../components/Separator";
import CanvasCanvas from "../components/CanvasCanvas";

export default class extends React.Component {
    render() {

        return (
            <Layout>
                <main>
                    <div className="loginBox5">
                        <Separator height={50}/>
                        <div className="center">
                            <h1>Game Play:</h1>
                            <Separator height={50}/>
                            <div id="PlayAreaImg" className="gameContainer">
                                <CanvasCanvas id={"Memes"}/>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <Separator height={350}/>
                    </div>
                </main>
            </Layout>
        )
    }
}
```

src/gameLogic.js

```
var keyState = {};
window.addEventListener('keydown',function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = true;
},true);
window.addEventListener('keyup',function(e){
    keyState[e.keyCode || e.which] = false;
},true);
x = 100;


function drawObj(ctx, object){
    var x = object[0];
    var y = object[1];
    var wid = object[2];
    var hei = object[3];
    var r = object[4];
    var g = object[5];
    var b = object[6];
    var t = object[7];
    // Renderer usage: Canvas context, x position, y position, object height, object width, red, green, blue, transparency
    ctx.fillStyle = "rgba("+String(r)+","+String(g)+","+String(b)+","+String(t)+")"; // colour ball
    ctx.fillRect (x, y, wid, hei); // render ball
    return ctx;
}


function renderAll(objects){
    console.log("### - Render: Starting - ###");
    for (var i = 0; i < objects.length; i++) {
        // Iterate over numeric indexes from 0 to 5, as everyone expects.
    }
    console.log("### - Render: Complete - ###");
}


//Define generic move function
function transformR(object, moveAmount, canvasHeight, canvasWidth){
    if (keyState[37]){
        object[0] -= moveAmount
        // console.log("left");
    }
    if (keyState[38]){
        object[1] -= moveAmount
        if (object[1] < 0){
            // console.log("Top Edge")
            object[1] = 0;
        }
        // console.log("up");
    }
    if (keyState[39]){
        object[0] += moveAmount
        // console.log("right");
    }
    if (keyState[40]){
        object[1] += moveAmount
        if (object[1] > (canvasHeight-object[3])){
            // console.log("Bottom Edge")
            object[1] = canvasHeight-object[3];
        }
        // console.log("down");
    }
    return object;
}


function transformL(object, moveAmount, canvasHeight, canvasWidth){
    if (keyState[65]){
        object[0] -= moveAmount
        // console.log("left");
    }
    if (keyState[87]){
        object[1] -= moveAmount
        if (object[1] < 0){
            // console.log("Top Edge")
            object[1] = 0;
        }
        // console.log("up");
    }
    if (keyState[68]){
        object[0] += moveAmount
        // console.log("right");
    }
    if (keyState[83]){
        object[1] += moveAmount
        if (object[1] > (canvasHeight-object[3])){
            // console.log("Bottom Edge")
            object[1] = canvasHeight-object[3];
        }
        // console.log("down");
    }
    return object;
}


function collisonDetect(ball, paddle){
    if (ball[0] < paddle[0] + paddle[2] &&
        ball[0] + ball[2] > paddle[0] &&
        ball[1] < paddle[1] + paddle[3] &&
        ball[3] + ball[1] > paddle[1]) {
        ball[8] = -ball[8];
        ball[9] = -ball[9];
        console.log("inside");
    } else {
        // console.log("not touching/inside");
    }
    return ball;
}




function ballMotion(height, width, ball, rightPaddle, leftPaddle){
    var x = ball[0];
    var y = ball[1];


    // collision detection
    ball = collisonDetect(ball, leftPaddle);
    ball = collisonDetect(ball, rightPaddle);
    var xSpeed = ball[8];
    var ySpeed = ball[9];
    x += xSpeed;
    y += ySpeed;

    // sides collison detection
    if (y <= 0){
        y = 0;
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }
    if (y >= height-ball[2]) {
        y = height-ball[2];
        ySpeed = -ySpeed;
    }

    if (x <= 0) {
        x = 0;
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        leftPoints +=1
    }
    if (x >= width-ball[3]) {
        x = width-ball[3];
        xSpeed = -xSpeed;
        rightPoints +=1
    }


    // assign new values
    ball[0] = x;
    ball[1] = y;
    ball[8] = xSpeed;
    ball[9] = ySpeed;
    return ball;
}


function onPositionUpdate(position){
    var lat = position.coords.latitude;
    var lng = position.coords.longitude;
    console.log("Current position: " + lat + " " + lng);
}


function onDown(event){
    cx = event.pageX;
    cy = event.pageY;
    console.log(cx, cy)
}

// Define objects as follows
// Renderer usage: Canvas context, x position, y position, object height, object width, red, green, blue, transparency
// Cut down usage: X, Y, height, width, red, green, blue, transparency
if (window.innerWidth < window.innerHeight) {
    ballDim = [window.innerWidth*.02, window.innerWidth*.02]
} else {
    ballDim = [window.innerHeight*.02, window.innerHeight*.02]
}
var ball = [window.innerWidth/2-((window.innerWidth*.02)/2), window.innerHeight*.8*.5-((window.innerHeight*.08)/2), ballDim[0], ballDim[1],200 ,200 ,200 ,3 , 3, 2];
var leftPaddle = [window.innerWidth*.01, window.innerHeight*.8*.5-((window.innerHeight*.08)/2), window.innerWidth*.01, window.innerHeight*.08, 0, 0, 200, 3];
var rightPaddle = [window.innerWidth*.8-(window.innerWidth*.01)-(window.innerWidth*.01), window.innerHeight*.8*.5-((window.innerHeight*.08)/2), window.innerWidth*.01, window.innerHeight*.08, 255, 100, 0, 3];
var leftPoints = 0;
var rightPoints = 0;

// Define gameLoop
function gameLoop(x,y) {
    if(navigator.geolocation){
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onPositionUpdate);
    } else {
        console.log("navigator.geolocation is not available");
    }
    var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
    var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
    canvas.addEventListener("mousedown",onDown,false);

    var width = window.innerWidth*.8;
    var height = window.innerHeight*.8
    ctx.canvas.width = width;
    ctx.canvas.height = height;

    var moveAmount = 3;
    var motionTicker = + new Date()

    // console.log(motionTicker)
    // move checking function

    leftPaddle[0] = window.innerWidth*.01;
    rightPaddle[0] = window.innerWidth*.8-(window.innerWidth*.01)-(window.innerWidth*.01);

    leftPaddle = transformL(leftPaddle, moveAmount, height, width);
    rightPaddle = transformR(rightPaddle, moveAmount, height, width);

    ball = ballMotion(height, width, ball, rightPaddle, leftPaddle);

    ctx.save();
    ctx.clearRect(0,0,width,height);
    // Render objects in frame
    drawObj(ctx, ball);
    drawObj(ctx, leftPaddle);
    drawObj(ctx, rightPaddle);
    ctx.font = String(window.innerWidth*.05)+"px Arial";
    ctx.fillStyle = "white";
    ctx.fillText(String(rightPoints)+" - "+String(leftPoints), window.innerWidth*.333, window.innerHeight*.1);
    ctx.restore();

    setTimeout(gameLoop, 1);
    await this.forceUpdate();
    this.state = {motionTicker}
}
```

/components/CanvasCanvas.js

```
import * as React from "react";

export default class extends React.Component {

    render() {
        return (
            <canvas ref={"canvas"} id = {"canvas"} width={640} height={425}/>
        )
    }


    async componentDidMount() {
        const script = document.createElement("script");
        console.log("ln14")
        script.src = "../src/gameLogic.js";
        script.async = true;
        // console.log(script);
        document.head.appendChild(script);
        console.log(script);

        await this.setState(
            {
                text: this.props.text,
                ...this.state
            }
        );
        await this.forceUpdate();
        const canvas = this.refs.canvas;
        const ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillText((this.state && this.state.text) ? this.state.text : "Not initialised (nullcheck)", 210, 75);
    }
}
```

Expected result is the gameLogic js file will render its output inside the canvas element and forceUpdate it at the end of each 'frame'.
And the actual result is a string of 404's as follows:

```
http://localhost:3000/css/style.css net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

```
index.js:1 Warning: Extra attributes from the server: deluminate_imagetype
```

```
GET http://localhost:3000/src/gameLogic.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)
```

Thanks for any help you can give in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access these files after compilation put them inside the `static` folder for example `script.src = "/static/gameLogic.js"`

Or use dynamic import

```
import dynamic from 'next/dynamic'
const gameLogic = dynamic(() => import(`../src/gameLogic.js`))
```

[dynamic-import doc](https://github.com/zeit/next.js#dynamic-import)

Comment: Thanks, I was kinda looking for a way to package them up and send them along with the page to the remote client